# java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlexception

I have this piece of code:

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String Username2 = request.getParameter("Username2");
    String Password2 = request.getParameter("Password2");
    String ResetPassword = request.getParameter("ResetPassword");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String st = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LoginAccount";
        Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(st, "root", "baljinder");
        Statement sta = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Account where Username='" + Username2 + "' && Password ='" + Password2 + "' ;");

        while (rs.next()) {

            if (Username2.equals(rs.getString("Username")) && Password2.equals(rs.getString("Password"))) {
                sta.executeUpdate("update Account set Password ='" + ResetPassword + "' where Username='" + Username2 + "' ;");
                out.print("your successful to Reset the password");
                conn.close();
            } else {
                out.println("<h1>the Username and Password didn't match did not found </h1>");
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AccountServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        //out.print(ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AccountServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        out.print(ex);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I'm getting this again & again,

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

any mistakes?

Comment: which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Btw... delightful sql injection attack you are creating. What website are you creating so that the world can have fun attacking it?

Comment: Darn. I was looking forward to a username of: '; delete from accounts; select from accounts where '1' == '

Comment: This is not a JSP/Servlet problem. You got an exception of `java.sql` package, not `javax.servlet` package. This is just a JDBC problem. You would have exactly the same problem when doing so in a normal Java class (where that piece of code *actually* belongs!). I removed the irrelevant JSP/Servlet tags.

Comment: By the way, why do you not trust the DB that it returned the row you asked it to return? You specfied the conditions in a `WHERE`, but you're checking them *again* by `equals()` inside the loop...

Comment: @BalusC - Can't always trust databases I guess, they like to keep you on your toes.

Answer (score 6):

You're closing the database connection while iterating through the `ResultSet`. A `ResultSet` needs to have its connection open to work.

You should also make sure to close the JDBC connection in a finally block.

Comment: If the username is strictly unique in the DB, then that `while` should better be an `if`. It would solve the problem as well, but it's definitely still not the right way. Resource closing should take place in a `finally` all the time.